# navbar collapse not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

try to start learning about Bootstrap. i create little code to create responsive menu, like this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Application Name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my question is, why when i try to select menu in small browser, menu does not show ?
can some one tell me why?
thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My geuss is that you didn't load jQuery. Place this in your header and see if it works:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also i suggest to load the bootstrap js file also in the header, just *after* the jQuery library.

Answer (score 5):

It is most likely because the bootstrap.js script relies on jQuery to work. Try including jQuery before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I noticed that on the bootstrap site its tells you to link js files in the footer.

I also had wordpress place them in my header as i had to enqueue the scripts in my functions.php file. Once i removed the link to the jquery.js file and bootstrap-min.js in the footer the nav button began to collapse correctly.

Comment: This is used to speed up loading of page and issue is because of the above told reason. @DemPorkChops